# while loop asks user input one time only

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct the_struct
{
 char FirstName[20];
 char LastName[32];
 int  Score[20];
};
int main ()
{
int i,n;
struct the_struct *ptr[100];
printf("how many students?\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
while (i<=n);
   {
   i==0;
   ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct the_struct));
   printf("Enter First Name \n");
   scanf("%s",ptr[i]->FirstName);
   printf("Enter Last Name \n");
   scanf("%s",ptr[i]->LastName);
   printf("Enter Score? \n");
   scanf("%s",ptr[i]->Score);
   printf("%s %s %s\n",ptr[i]->FirstName,ptr[i]->LastName,ptr[i]->Score);
   i++;
   }

}
```

hey guys, so when i enter the first input, it goes only once without going on for the number the user inputs, i tried the for loop but same result. 
still learning C so my apology if i misunderstood something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: get rid of the `;` after `while(i<=n)`

Comment: When i remove the ; when it asks for number of students it ends the program, but it allows me to enter a letter as a first name and ignoring the student number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is problematic. You could rewrite it as:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
   ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct the_struct));
   printf("Enter First Name \n");
   scanf("%s",ptr[i]->FirstName);
   printf("Enter Last Name \n");
   scanf("%s",ptr[i]->LastName);
   printf("Enter Score? \n");
   scanf("%s",ptr[i]->Score);
   printf("%s %s %s\n",ptr[i]->FirstName,ptr[i]->LastName,ptr[i]->Score);
}
```

And since you use `%s` to read and print `Score`, you should declare it as `char Score[20];` instead of `int`.

Comment: that worked!! 
i'm just printing to know the input is working or not.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `i` is uninitialized. Therefore, the loop `while (i <= n)` has undefined behavior, and can end at any time.

Add `int i = 0` initializer to fix this problem.

Notes:

1. `i == 0` expression at the beginning of the loop has no effect
2. Since `i` starts at zero, your `while` loop should be `while (i < n)`, not `<=`.
3. You should check the results of `scanf` to see if the user entered something meaningful
4. You should specify the size of the array into which you read a string, e.g. `scanf("%31s",ptr[i]->LastName);` This prevents buffer overruns.

Comment: i changed the while loop like you said, same result.
tried also the for loop same result.

Comment: @Ankosh You need to remove the semicolon after your loop, too. [Here is a demo](http://ideone.com/Qrasgf)